# Использование PHP как сервера, отправка массива с его помощью

Tags: php

Я пишу сайты на ReactJS и PHP использую на серверной части для работы с БД, я привык к этому с колледжа и не очень хочется учить node.js, но у меня есть проблема, когда я отправляю запрос с фронта

```
fetch('http://localhost/projects/server_blog/index.php',{
           method: 'POST',
           body: form
       })
           .then (response => response.text())
           .then(response => {
               let a = response.split(';');
```

Это мой стандартный запрос на данные и то, как я их обрабатываю.
А сами данные с сервера отправляю в виде строки

```
if(isset($_POST['Projects'])){
    require_once 'login.php';  
    $conn = mysqli_connect($hn, $un, $pw, $db); 
    if (!$conn) die('Невозможно запустить mysql');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projects";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Ресурс не найден');
    $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($j=0;$j<$rows;++$j)
    {$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo($row[0].'^'.$row[1].'^'.$row[2].'^'.$row[3].'^'.$row[4].'^'.$row[5].'^'.$row[6].'^'.$row[7].';');
    } 
}
```

Если вкратце, в серверной части я проверяю какой именно приходит запрос с помощью isset и в случае true подключаюсь к бд и отправляю данные с неё, но есть одна проблема, я хотел бы это делать в виде массива или объекта, но даже не представляю как это сделать хотя-бы примерно и из-за этого приходится изворачиваться со строчными методами, переводя строку в массив разбивая её по символам, в целом метод работает, но я уверен, что это очень медленно и не правильно, как вы реализуете отправку данных, хотел бы посмотреть на чужие решения.

Comment: Скажите, вы *правда* никогда не слышали слово JSON?

Comment: @Ипатьев, JSON еще не изобрели.

Comment: Я использовал JSON ранее, но локально на фронте, через сервер на PHP никогда не прокидывал, хотя очень хотелось бы научиться, я просто долго не мог найти информации о том, как отправить данные из JSON с помощью PHP, а потом решил делать по старинке, сейчас решил обратиться за помощью так как устал бороться со строками

Comment: Не очень понимаю, для чего вы так язвите, думаю на старте у всех бывали проблемы с самыми простыми задачами.

Comment: [JSON с помощью PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=JSON+%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E+PHP) Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А если из MySQL доставать данные, а не из JSON файла, то как их отправить в формате массива?

Comment: Ты дубликат-то прочитал вообще? Там вот прям черным по белому - результаты запроса в MySQL кладутся в JSON.

Comment: Всё, увидел, благодарю

Comment: Только надо сначала собрать все данные в массив, а не этот ужас с отправкой каждой строки отдельно, как сейчас. для mysqli можно использовать mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC). А то же ведь опять вопросы начнутся

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам, но прошу, будьте не так критичны к новичкам в вашем ремесле, я просто не до конца научился понимать информацию в документации полностью, порой что-то не получается использовать или найти и приходится искать помощь более опытных коллег.

Comment: А на клиенте соответственно `.then (response => response.json())`

Comment: @Ипатьев А вы случаем не знаете, как с сервера PHP отправить изображение или файл? 
У меня в бд хранится путь до файла, хранящийся на сервере, я бы хотел чтобы файл отправлялся вместе с остальной информацией, пробовал через base64, но как-то громоздко получается, хочу узнать нормальный путь передачи файла.

Comment: @Ипатьев Ещё почитал ваши ответы на вопросы связанные с изображениями, вы не рекомендовали использовать blob, значит и base64 крайне не удачный вариант, но вы вообще не сказали как надо отправлять, я так и не понял после часа гугления как отправить картинку или файл с сервера php, начитался про какой-то Curl, но это же тоже сторонний метод какой-то, неужто в php нет встроенной передачи файла?

Comment: Передавать надо не файл, а ссылку на него